# How to get the value inside <span> element of an iframe

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've two iframes named Test1 & Test2 and inside every iframe there are below code snippet. I Want to get the value '24' inside the .

```
<div class="Test-font"> 
  <h6 class="Test_something d-inline">Available MQ Connections: </h6>
  <span class= "d-inline" id="availcons">24</span>
</div>
```

I used the below code. I get the value for first  Test1 but I didn't get any result for the second iframe. Even no error.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("Test1"))
Test_1_connections = driver.find_element_by_id("availcons").text

driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("Test2"))
Test_2_connections = driver.find_element_by_class_id("availcons").text
```

I expect 24 in the output, but I am getting nothing but a black screen.

Comment: Is the Test2 iframe available when you switch to default content from Test1? E.g. do you need to click something so the Test2 appears?

Comment: I have an anchor <a> to click on to see the data in the Iframe. I added the driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id = "home-tab"]').click() after default_content(). Still same result is coming. One more thing to add, I can see the data of the other iframes when I am inspecting elements.

Comment: You should add a wait condition for the availcons item to be clickable.

Comment: can you post your url?

Comment: Still not working. I got ame result.

Comment: @SubhajitPodder, how is going? Did you try my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the explicit wait for the availability of iframe and then do action within it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "Test1")))
```

Hope it helps you!